# How to use Dynamic Routing to trigger the same .js in pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have multiple routes for e.g:

1. /solutions/
2. /solutions/web-development/
3. /features/
4. /features/flexbox/
5. /plugins/
6. /plugins/permalink/

and so on.

I would like to run the same file (`abc.js`) for all of these routes. I have checked the [Dynamic Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing) Section of Next.js but according to that section, My understanding is that I need to create multiple directories and copy the same file on multiple instances.

Is there any way by which I can run the single file for all the **DEFINED** routes or for the whole site?

**EDIT:** I know that there is a way to do that by creating [Custom Server and manually add dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-routes-using-props-from-url) **BUT** I am looking to achieve this without the creation of the external server.

Comment: Not sure about 'next/router', but with 'react-dom-router' this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: what about using Hoc pattern? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to tackle this thing. This can be done using the `next.config.js` file. The only thing which you needed is the page **URLs** and then you can apply the same file or even add conditions to apply using multiple files.

Here is the sample code:

```js
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function(
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    const paths = {};
    const pageURLs = [
      '/solutions/',
      '/solutions/web-development/',
      '/features/',
      '/features/flexbox/',
      '/plugins/',
      '/plugins/permalink/'
    ];

    var loopInit = 0;
    var loopCount = pageURLs.length;
    var url = '';
    for (loopInit = 0; loopInit < loopCount; loopInit += 1) {
      url = pageURLs[loopInit];
      switch(url) {
        case '/solutions/':
          paths[`${url}`] = {
            page: '/solutions',
            query: {
              slug: url
            }
          };
          break;
        case '/features/':
          paths[`${url}`] = {
            page: '/features',
            query: {
              slug: url
            }
          };
          break;
        default:
          paths[`${url}`] = {
            page: '/',
            query: {
              slug: url
            }
          };
          break;
      }
    }

    return paths;
  },
  exportTrailingSlash: true
};
```

In the above example, I have hardcoded the URLs in `pageURLs` variable. You can pass dynamic values in it like get Permalinks from **WordPress**, URL Alias from **Drupal** or from any other **CMS** or **Headless CMS**, etc.

In the switch case, I am applying different templates on `/solutions/` and `/features/`. For the remaining URLs, I am applying a single template.

**NOTE:** `page: '/'` refers `index.js` under *pages* directory similarly, `page: '/solutions'` refers `solutions.js` under pages directory and so on. It can be changed/vary as per developer choice.

I have tested this solution on the `9.1.4` version of **Next.js**. Please refer to the **Next.js** documentation for further details.

1. https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-configuration
2. https://nextjs.org/docs#usage

**EDITED:** This solution works for both server-side rendering and `Next.js` export.

Comment: It doesn't work in production with non static pages

Comment: @Meliborn On which NEXT.js version you are working on? I have tested this solution on the 9.1.4 version of NEXT.js as I mentioned in the answer and might be this solution is no longer applicable on the newer versions.

Comment: 10+, but there is https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites for this